# Oracle sql statement, how to created good statement for current case?

Tags: oracle

I have a table which looks like this

| id | name | problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | Good |
| 2 | A2 | Bad |
| 1 | A1 | Good |
| 2 | A2 | Good |

What I expect to recive from this table, for unique `id`, and `name`, we can have different `problem`,

E.g.:

- If **A1 = Good** for all cases, I need to return `1   A1   Good`,
- If **A2 = Good** and also **A2 = Bad**, I need to return `2   A2   Bad`

Expected result should looks like

| id | name | problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | Good |
| 2 | A2 | Bad |

Comment: So, you need to return Bad for A2, when out of the two values in the table, it has one Bad. If both values for A2 would have been Good, you would have returned Good for A2. right?

Comment: Can you read your question again and confirm that is clear enough? What you explained and what you posted as expected output is not so clear.

Comment: @realspirituals what exactly is not so clear?

Comment: A1 = good for all cases then retrun A1=Good, if not what to return? Also A2=Good and also A2=Bad return A2=Bad, if not???

Comment: if i have two rows A1 Bad and A1 good, result should be A1 Bad.  If A1 Good,A1 Good result should be A1 Good.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the solution from it. Please, post it as a proper answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (although I'm not 100% sure I understand the problem)

```
select id, 
       name, 
       case 
          when total_count = good_count then 'Good' 
          else 'Bad'
       end as problem
from (
  select id, 
         name,
         count(*) as total_count, 
         case (when problem = 'Good' then 1 end) as good_count
  from the_table
  group by id, name
)
```

This counts the total items for each id/name combination and counts the number of "Good" items. If the total count equals the "good" count that `Good` will be displayed otherwise 'Bad'